# Changing color of newly created line feature on mouseover in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, line, feature-layer, qgis2web, function

How to highlight one feature on hover from a featureGroup layer?

It's easy when the layer is predefinied and static - I could write a highlighFeature and onEachFeature functions and pass them as options when creating a layer (like in the code created with qgis2web plugin).

But in my code I create line layer inside the code which creates point layer like this:

```
var linesFeatures = L.featureGroup();
var pointsLayer = L.geoJSON(points, {
    pane: 'pointsPane',
    pointToLayer: (feature, latlng) => {
        const div = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML = `${feature.properties.name}<br>`;
    
        const button = document.createElement("button");
        button.innerHTML = "Create Line";
    
        button.onclick = function() {
            const line1 = L.polyline(
                [latlng, [10, 5]],
                {color: 'black',})
                .bindPopup(feature.properties.name);
                linesFeatures.addLayer(line1)
        };
    
        div.appendChild(button);
    
        return L.marker(latlng).bindPopup(div);
    }
    });
linesFeatures.addTo(map);
```

My **first** solution based on a highlightFeature from the code created with qgis2web plugin doesn't work and I don't know why:

```
function highlightFeature(e) {
    var layer = e.target;
    layer.setStyle({
        color: 'red'
    });
};
function resetHighlight(e) {
    var layer = e.target;
    layer.resetStyle(e.target);
};
function onEachFeature (feature, layer) {
    layer.on({mouseover: highlightFeature,
            mouseout: resetHighlight})
};
```

With these 3 functions above I add onEachFeature inside the code creating a line:

```
button.onclick = function() {
    const line1 = L.polyline(
        [latlng, [10, 5]],
        {color: 'black',
        onEachFeature: onEachFeature
        })
        .bindPopup(feature.properties.name);
        linesFeatures.addLayer(line1)
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nt284j9r/

My **second** solution with layer.on method works partially, because I want to highlight only a one line on hover and it makes to change color of all the lines from the lines layer. I don't know how to write to make it highlight only one line. I was trying to change var layer to the var feature and passing it as an argument byt it didn' work.

```
linesFeatures.on('mouseover', function(e) {
    var layer = e.target;
    layer.setStyle({color: 'green'});
});

linesFeatures.on('mouseout', function(e) {
    var layer = e.target;
    layer.setStyle({color: 'red'});
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hsc6n2am/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first solution doesn't work because `L.polyline` has no such thing as `onEachFeature` option.

Your second solution highlights all polylines because you attach events to `linesFeatures` group layer which contains all the lines.

Solution is to attach events to individual lines while they are created. Since `linesFeatures` layer is general group layer, not GeoJSON layer, it does not have  `.resetStyle` method to reset member's layer style. One possible solution for this is to store default line style in some custom property (let's say `defaultStyle`) with name that's not in conflict with standard Leaflet properties.

Code could then look something like this:

```
function highlightFeature(e) {
  var layer = e.target;
  layer.setStyle({
    color: 'red'
  });
};
function resetHighlight(e) {
  var layer = e.target;
  layer.setStyle(layer.defaultStyle);
};

var linesFeatures = L.featureGroup();
var pointsLayer = L.geoJSON(points, {
  pointToLayer: (feature, latlng) => {
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = `${feature.properties.name}<br>`;

    const button = document.createElement("button");
    button.innerHTML = "Create Line";

    button.onclick = function() {
      var lineStyle = {color: 'black'}
      const line1 = L.polyline(
        [latlng, [10, 5]],
        lineStyle
      ).bindPopup(feature.properties.name);
      line1.defaultStyle = lineStyle;
      line1.on({
        mouseover: highlightFeature,
        mouseout: resetHighlight
      });
      linesFeatures.addLayer(line1);
    };

    div.appendChild(button);

    return L.marker(latlng).bindPopup(div);
  }
}).addTo(map);
linesFeatures.addTo(map);
```

Comment: I knew onEachFeature may not work with line layer but I showed how I was trying to solve this problem. The same with featureGroup, I knew that it containes all the lines and that’s why it highlights all the lines. But I didn’t think to add the code when creating lines. Anyway I wouldn’t come up witch such a solution as I’m learning Leaflet in this project. Thanks a lot!